# @googlemail.com account can't auth with GoogleSignIn, but the @gmail.com account can

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin, google-account

Recently I received some user feedback that can't sign in google account to access Google Drive app data in my app.
Found that they all use @googlemail.com email address.
After testing, @googlemail.com account stoped at a loading page(the Screen Record bellow).
But @gmail.com account didn't open this page and sign in success.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();
            GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(MainActivity.this, gso);
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

[image]

Comment: The @googlemail.com email address account most from Germany